# How to reference rotation of every instance

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector, simulation-nodes

I'm trying out simulations in geo nodes and I want to have the cones (instances) to move around and follow each other, similarly to a school of fish. I currently have this set up,
[image]
I want to get the rotation of every instance to connect to the normalise node and progressively rotate every instance to a common direction.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The rotation you want to reach is given by an empty in this example.

[image]

Invert instance current rotations and rotate the empty rotation by it. So that we have the rotation to reach from each instance point of view.

Then take some amount of this rotation (mix vector node with factor as rotation speed) and rotate the instances with it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 because as shown on screen capture it works :D But I'm worried scaling (that's what effectively the mix node does) the Euler rotation might give 'unnatural' results, and it's probably better to Mix in "Rotation" mode (using the new pink = quaternion sockets)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, ok understood. Could be a rotation mix instead. But as provided in Euler in the right order, do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: quaternion rotation is the shortest path, whereas Euler is linear interpolation of the XYZ components, and that's not the same, which I think I show clearly here: [tree](https://i.imgur.com/od132Zk.png) [gif](https://i.imgur.com/mgM21aG.gif) [blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/3WlAGLoK/) BTW, while this is an extreme example and in practice the interpolations will happen over much smaller range of angles (because they happen all the time), you can produce an even more extreme example: an euler interpolation of 0° to 360° is one rotation, and quaternion is... No movement at all.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, Markus, thanks, this is clear. Some kind of mix of rotation will give the "shortest path" to the max rotation... But not sure this is preferable in all cases. But that understood, Thanks. I think the OP may read all this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking to use the vector of the other instances and not an external source so i can create more organic and fluid-like motion and potentialy have two groups colide and split, instead of following a predefined path.

Comment: @FelixGroves, could you detail all that in your question more accurately? Because the normalize node is linked to nothing in the question.

Comment: « I want to get the rotation of every instance to connect to the normalise node »

Comment: So, just replace the object info node by the normalize node. Right?